# Attribute does not update on saving dup(licated) ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model with several fields I'd like to duplicate, but I would like to change one of the attributes, namely the `units` attribute.

So I go:

```
new_item = old_item.dup
new_item.units = 0
```

I pass this to the template, and allow the user to designate a number of units.

Then I simply go:

```
new_item.units = params[:units]
new_item.save
```

But the value I get is always the value of the original ActiveRecord instance.

In fact, if you do this:

```
new_item = old_item.dup
new_item.units = 0
new_item.units = 500
new_item.save
```

The value of `new_item.units` will be `old_item.units`.

What is going on here?

I'm on:

```
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [i686-linux]
Rails 4.0.5
```

Comment: I did the same in my rails console. It works. While you did `new_item.save`, does it return `true` or `false`  ?

Comment: Updated my answer with the versions of Ruby/Rails.  Save returns `true`.

Comment: That means. record got saved. How you then confirming, it is not got saved ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The item does get saved, but the `units` field doesn't change to the new value(`500`), it remains the same as the `old_item.units` field.

Comment: I mean are you checking in the database if it got saved or not ?

Comment: Yes, it saves incorrectly,.  What version of Ruby/Rails are you on?

Comment: 4.1(Rails) and 2.1(ruby). After updating try `reload!`.. and then check.

Comment: Possibly a bug that was fixed then.

Comment: I did reload! and I've checked all the return values and verified the database values, this is definitely a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verified with another user on Rails 4.0.5 that this is a bug which has been fixed in 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

You should sanitise your `params[:units]` as strong params (see http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html). Please, check out logs for phrase like *Unpermitted parameters: units*. If that, just add `params.permit(:units)`.

Comment: This is not the problem.  Forget about the params, that was just per illustration, simply try to re-assign the units field and save and see what you get.